# Accidentally added yeast before pectolase :/

Tags: fruit-wine

I'm fairly new to homebrewing, and I'm currently making some mango wine. Now stupidly my pectolase and yeast are in very similar looking containers and I've just added my yeast (thinking it was pectolase) to my fruit mash. 
In a panic to try to save it, I immediately added the pectolase and gave it a good stir. Temp was about 34degrees celcius.

Someone please tell me everything will be fine?

Comment: Yes, probably it will be fine if the yeast can take that temperature. It probably can, but check the package.

Comment: It will still be drinkable just may have a slight haze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this Homebrew Talk thread](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showthread.php?t=239080) it seems like the primary reason pectolase is added earlier in the process is due to low alcohol tolerance. However there should have been virtually no alcohol when you added the pectolase as it takes hours for yeast to multiply and begin fermentation.

Depending on how vigorous your fermentation is and possibly many other factors you could potentially end up with extra pectins in the final product or have simple saved yourself some time. It may be hard to say.

[This Winemaking Talk post](http://www.winemakingtalk.com/forum/showthread.php?t=32778) suggests that this is a topic people are split on.  It seems at least that some people add both at the same time with no perceived ill effect, which is promising for your situation.

As with many things in homebrewing, you probably didn't ruin your batch (at least not too much) and regardless you have another variable to play with in the future to figure out how to make what you like to drink.

Comment: Aah thanks!  

Checked this morning and it is indeed fermenting :)

Comment: When yeast meets a moderate to high concentration of sugar, alcohol production begins immediately. It's called the [Crabtree effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crabtree_effect) I don't think it changes the answer, just saying.